# Highlight alternative rows but not blanks?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, row, conditional-formatting

I am using the following formula in a conditional format in order to highlight every other row on my spreadsheet:

```
=MOD(ROW(),2)=0
```

This works fine, however it highlights all rows whether blank or not. I don't want to highlight blank rows.

Please could someone show me how to do this?

Comment: `=OR(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,A1 = "")`  Change A1 to the first row of conditional formatting applies to row and a column that is always used until the full row is empty.

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you for your suggestion, however, it appears that if I use your code, and change the cell ref to the first row of conditional formatting as suggested - this causes my conditional formatting to go all over the place. And I get random cells coloured all over the place.

Comment: Sorry, make the column of A1 Absolute: `=OR(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,$A1 = "")`

Answer (score 1):

Select the range to apply the formatting to, starting at Row1 and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(ISEVEN(ROW()),A1<>"")
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

This assumes you want to skip formatting a row if just the ColumnA cell in it is blank.

An alternative would be to stick with what you have but add another rule, giving it priority, just to test if the ColumnA cell is blank and then set "no formatting" for that.